# IBM Worklight - Is it possible to deploy an app on iPhone device without a Mac and Xcode?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I don't have macbook pro but I do have an iPhone 4S.
Can I deploy a Worklight app on iPhone without using a Mac and Xcode?

Comment: Install VMware and then install macOS under VMware, that will work But very very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deploy a Worklight application on an iOS device without first going through Xcode (the iOS IDE), which can be used only on Mac.

The Worklight Studio plug-in for Eclipse generates the Xcode project to be used.
The next step is to open it in Xcode.

So again, w/out a Mac and Xcode, you cannot proceed to deploying your application (unless you want to use some 3rd party provider and give him your developer signing identity and private key, which would be highly insecure(!)).

The answer is No.